# how to handle upload the records to server using dispatch method in ios5

Tags: iphone, ios, upload, grand-central-dispatch

I have 500 records in my local files. I want to upload the files to server using dispatch method in NSURLConnection. My thought is the count of the records is 50 reached then upload as First come first out method using dispatch_queue. How can i done this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you have a large amount of files its a good practice to work on threads, either you use the performSelectorInBackground or dispatch_async.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    // code to post on server
});
```

here is the good post about dispatch_async http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2011/02/28/cocoa-touch-tutorial-using-grand-central-dispatch-for-asynchronous-table-view-cells/